# Does there exist $f$ such that $f(n)=\Omega(\log n)$ and $(f(n))^2=O(f(n))$?

Tags: functions, asymptotics

I have to prove/disprove the next 2 statements.  I've succeeded with the  second, not with the first.

1. There exists $f$ such that $f(n)=\Omega(\log n)$ and  $(f(n))^2=O(f(n))$.
2. If $f$ and $g$ are monotonically increasing functions, such that $ f(g(n)) = O(n) $  and $f(n)=\Omega(n)$ then $g(n)=O(n)$.

Comment: I formatted the formulas; please check they are what you meant.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: If $f(n)^2 \le K |f(n)|$ and $f(n) \ne 0$, then $|f(n)| \ldots$

Comment: I'm really trying to understand it but I don't.. what should I do?

Comment: @user3479031: Try to cancel $|f(n)|$.

Comment: so is there any solution? I am stuck at this problem too, by the way what if $f(n) \geq 1$ is it still possible?

Comment: $|f(n)| \le K$ for large $n$, so it's not $\Omega(\log n)$.

Comment: @RobertIsrael thank you a lot... and what about the second question?

Comment: Are you using the Hardy-Littlewood or Knuth definition of $\Omega$?