# If $f$ and $g$ are monotonically increasing functions, such that $f(g(n))=O(n)$ and $f(n)=Ω(n)$ then $g(n)=O(n)$

Tags: functions, asymptotics, computer-science, monotone-functions

I am stuck at the following question:

This question has already been asked on this forum [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1540731/does-there-exist-f-such-that-fn-omega-log-n-and-fn2-ofn/1540744#comment4963941_1540744) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1723889/if-f-and-g-are-monotonically-increasing-functions-such-that-fgn-on-and-f)

In the first link the question didn't receive any answers especially the part that I am interested in,
and about the second link honestly I am not sure it is possible to do it the way they did.

> If $f$ and $g$ are monotonically increasing functions, such that
>   $f(g(n))=O(n)$ and $f(n)=Ω(n)$ then $g(n)=O(n)$.

I think I understand what is going on but I am struggling to prove it.

We know that $f(n)$ grows at least as fast as $n$ so if $g(n)$ will grow faster then $n$ -

$f(g(n))$ will grow faster then $n$ which will lead us to $f(g(n)) \neq O(n)$ and we will get a contradiction.
The problem is that I have no Idia how to format the answer correctly.

Please help me if you can.

Answer (score 1):

The facts that $f(n) \in \Omega(n)$ and $f(g(n)) \in O(n)$ tell us that 
$\frac{f(g(n))}{n} \le C_1$ and $C_2 \le \frac{f(n)}{n} \le C_3$ (for $n$ large enough). Now, if $g(n)$ is unbounded, then the quotient $\frac{f(g(n))}{g(n)}$ behaves like $\frac{f(n)}{n}$ and gets larger than, say, $C_2/2$. Then
$$\frac{f(g(n))}{n} = \frac{f(g(n))}{n}\cdot \frac{g(n)}{g(n)} = \frac{f(g(n))}{g(n)}\cdot\frac{g(n)}{n}$$

shows, because the LHS is bounded above by $C_1$, that we must have $\frac{g(n)}{n} \le C$ for some $C$ also, since otherwise the RHS would grow arbitrarily large, given that $\frac{f(g(n))}{g(n)}$ would be bounded below and $\frac{g(n)}{n}$ would diverge to infinity.

Otherwise, if $g(n)$ is bounded, then it tends to a limit $L$, and we obviously have $\frac{g(n)}{n} \to 0$ since the numerator tends to $L$ and the denominator to $\infty$.

Comment: As far as I know, $f(g(n)) \in O(n)$ just means $|f(g(n))| \leq C \cdot n$ (for $n$ large enough). I don't think that this implies $\frac{f(g(n))}{n} \to 0$. Maybe you are confusing the big-O notation with the little-o notation?

Comment: @PhoemueX I believe I fixed any mistakes - please feel free to have a look. I appreciate the correction!